# Setting up usage tracking with Direct insert set to No

Tags: obiee

I'm trying to set up OBIEE 10g usage tracking feature and dashboard reports, with Direct Insert equals to No i.e. with flat file.
I have deployed/merged usage RPD and catalog with my existing RPD/catalog and set NQSConfig.ini parameters accordingly (DIRECT_INSERT=NO).

However, I'm the usage tracking reports fail to run due to some ORA error. This is obvious since these reports are being redirected to database (probably these are setup for DIRECT_INSERT=Yes)

`State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 17001] Oracle Error code: 12154, message: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified at OCI call OCIServerAttach. [nQSError: 17014] Could not connect to Oracle database. (HY000)`

How can I configure these reports to work with the log file (DIRECT_INSERT=NO).
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use flat file instead of database to store the data? If you want to report against it (which is a good idea) then it makes a lot more sense to just load it into the database directly. This is how every UT implementation I've ever seen has been done.

Comment: Hi rmoff, agreed DB approach is better. But I'm doing a POC on this feature and DB changes are out of question as of now. So I'm triying to run these reports on the log file. No success as of now. Any ideas on the configuration? Do I need to change the usage tracking connection pool settings in the RPD so that the requests are redirected to the log file?